# I'm building a react native app and I'm confused about something

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm confused about using "Modal" or whole screen for error and informative pages! any suggestions ?

I think using a screen for just informative or error pages can decrease performance!

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  The size of a window has no impact on performance.  The performance of informational dialogs is almost always irrelevant, because the display time is dwarfed by the human reading time.

Comment: I thought the way of implementing a screen and navigating to it could be slower than just showing up a quick Modal!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will always have resources to use both of these approaches without any problems. Figure out the best ux and go with it